# Mocha and Chai test expect not to throw error

Tags: mocha.js, chai

I am doing some testing with Mocha and Chai

I have some functions that don't have a return value but if there is an error they throw an Error

I would like to test as the are passing the test if they don't throw an Error

for example

```
async function sum(a, b){
    Promise.resolve()
    .then()
    if(typeof(a) !== 'number')
        throw new Error('a should be a number')

    if(typeof(b) !== 'number')  
        throw new Error('b should be a number')

    console.log('the sum is ', a + b)

    return
}
```

Then I want to test that it is working with something like this

```
expect(sum(1, 2)).not.to.throw()
```

Comment: What for `Promise.resolve().then()`?

Comment: @slideshowp2, thanks for the comment. In the actual code I have more complex functions that are async

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to solve this was to use `chai-as-promise` library

```
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiAsPromised = require("chai-as-promised");
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
const expect = chai.expect;

expect(sum(1, 2)).to.eventually.not.be.rejectedWith(Error)
```